adb reverse tcp:8080 tcp:8080 for any domain?
Access server on host from android device for USB debugging:
adb reverse tcp:8080 tcp:8080

It works for localhost. Can it work for other domains?
On server hosts file:
127.0.0.1  my.example.com

From android device:
access: my.example.com:8080

it was not forwarded to the host for my.example.com.
The adb reverse command does not limit to localhost only.

Port forwarding is nice for single services on a server, but for multiple http servers you should use a proxy. The connection to the proxy can be tunneled via port forwarding. Use a proxy that just forwards connections without https interception. Or try USB tethering.

USB tethering? forward port for any domain?

Your problem is not port forwarding but name resolution, as your device does not know what my.example.com is.

Any simple DNS solution that the Android/iOS device can use for resolving fake domains?
